# How can I get the auto-generated keys in an INSERT statement using RPostgreSQL in R

Tags: r, rpostgresql

I cannot find a way to get the auto-generated keys after an INSERT statement when using the R database interface to PostgreSQL (`RPostgreSQL`).

Is there a way to do this like in JDBC?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getGeneratedKeys%28%29

Comment: I think the general answer is to a) find out of the C level API supports it and b) if so, maybe discuss a patch to the package to expose it.  Otherwise, "cheat" and run `select` after `insert` ?

Comment: Curious, why do you need the auto-generated keys after `INSERT`? Usually these are not exposed literally in application layer but only to join tables in SQL statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eventually, I have exploited a PostgreSQL-specific SQL extension, the `RETURNING` clause of an `INSERT` statement, which returns the generated primary key(s) after executing an `INSERT` statement. It was also necessary to trick `DBI` to handle the `INSERT` query as if it were a `SELECT` query to get access to the returned values, i.e. the generated keys.

Assume we have the following table in a database: `USERS(id, name)`, where the `id` is the auto-generated primary key. The following example R code snippet illustrates the concept of getting the generated key from the database, and assigning it to the R object:

```
query <- sprintf(
  "INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ('%s') RETURNING id",
  users$name
)

dbres = dbGetQuery(conn, query)
users$id = dbres$id
```